# Script for starting pycharm with from command prompt

Tags: python, pycharm, command-prompt

I added the bin folder of pycharm to my path in Ubuntu. When I start pycharm from command prompt I have to type `./phcharm.sh` in the command prompt. How can I change it so that program starts by simply typing `pycharm` at command prompt?

Comment: You can write a script that [starts with  `#!/bin/sh`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), call it `pycharm`, [mark it executable](https://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html), and put it somewhere [on your `PATH`](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html).

Comment: we can symlink to /usr/bin to access from anywhere this will also work right.

Answer (score 0):

follow the steps mentioned below

```
1> go the pycharm.sh directory run this command

    chmod +x phcharm.sh

2>  sudo ln -sf $PWD/phcharm.sh /usr/bin/phcharm
3>  phcharm
```

now the shell script will be executed.

now you can access this from any folder.